# Spring Cloud conexion Git not autorized

Tags: github, microservices, spring-cloud

cual es la configuracion actual estoy usando spring 3.2.1

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/username/repository.git: not authorized `#

Application Configuration

```
server.port=8081 

\# Spring Cloud Config Server profile spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true

 # Spring Cloud Config Server Configuration spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/user/repository.git spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths=config-data

 spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=${GIT_USER} 

spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=${GIT_PASSWORD}\
```